# Graph API Explorer returns different data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-fql, checkin

If I query following FQL statement:

```
SELECT checkin_id, author_uid, page_id FROM checkin WHERE page_id ='PAGE_ID'
```

the Graph API Explorer returns me the correct result, in my case 3 friends have check-in to the page.

However if I execute the same statement for the same page with the same permissions on my mobile android app, just 1 friend's check-in is returned. However I have set all needed permissions for this query. If I use the token generated by the Graph API Explorer and set it manually in my app the right result is being returned.

Finally I have compared both the Graph API Explorer and the app token by using the Access Token Debugger with following result:

APP token permissions:

**Scopes**: create_note, friends_likes, friends_status, photo_upload, publish_actions, publish_stream, read_friendlists, read_stream, share_item, status_update, user_activities, user_likes, user_status, video_upload

Graph API Explorer token permissions:

**Scopes**: friends_likes, friends_status, read_friendlists, read_stream, user_likes, user_status

So I'm a little bit confused. Does the Facebook API handles web and mobile queries in a different way?

thx and cheers Chris

Comment: Well, I have set all possible permissions for my app, unfortunaletly it made no differences. After that I made another try and overrode the app token by the web-token generated by the Graph API Explorer and surprise surprise I got the correct result. However that's not a solution because first of all it's the web-token and second the web-token is valid for only one hour.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm currently seeing something similar where a token from the API Explorer works, but a token from my Android application doesn't.

Comment: Unfortunately not, after a couple of days trying different things I gave up :/